# Nullpointerexception custom Adapter at getview no inflater

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Whenever I scroll down in my android app, I get a nullpointerexception on line 79
**linear.addView(holder.rbg);**
I tried several solutions but none of them seem to work, since I don't use an inflater because I have no idea how it works.
I can provide you my XML file but the only thing inside it is a linearlayout.

```
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
            super(context, -1, -1, strings);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       //trying to reuse a recycled view
            ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;
            LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(Bouwonderdeel.this);
            if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
           linear.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           linear.setId(50);
            holder.tv = new TextView(Bouwonderdeel.this);
            holder.tv.setId(100);

            holder.rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouwonderdeel.this);
            holder.rbg.setId(200);
            holder.rbg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
            holder.rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                }
            });
            //Make the list Items containing radiobuttons en textviews.
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        holder.rName = new RadioButton (Bouwonderdeel.this);
                        holder.rbg.addView(holder.rName);
            }  

            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

             linear.addView(holder.rbg);
             linear.addView(holder.tv);
             holder.tv.setText(super.getItem(position));

            return linear;

        }
    }
  static class ViewHolder{
        RadioButton rName;
        RadioGroup rbg;
        TextView tv;
        }
```

http://shrib.com/4RBAO1Ia

Comment: Can you provide logs !

Comment: @ppuskar check edit, posted it in a Online notepad so the comment isn't miles long.

Comment: return convertView instead linear in getView();

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana When I call convertView, it gives a blank page on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code by this,

```
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
                super(context, -1, -1, strings);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       //trying to reuse a recycled view
                ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnlayout);
    linear.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                        AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnlayout);
    holder.rbg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnlayout);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()
    }



               linear.setId(50);

                holder.tv.setId(100);


                holder.rbg.setId(200);
                holder.rbg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
                holder.rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                    }
                });
                //Make the list Items containing radiobuttons en textviews.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            holder.rName = new RadioButton (Bouwonderdeel.this);
                            holder.rbg.addView(holder.rName);
                }  

                }
                else{
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                }

                 linear.addView(holder.rbg);
                 linear.addView(holder.tv);
                 holder.tv.setText(super.getItem(position));

                return convertView;

            }
        } 
hope it will help you
```

Comment: **holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnlayout);**
How do these tags work? since I have no textviews in the layout, until created?

Comment: Cant seem to find it out :/

Comment: This is rather ambiguous but a tag is basically a data packet in the form of an Object. You create the holder, give it data and then set it as a Tag on the convertView as extra data. You don't know which convertView you are going to get back, but thanks to Tag you get your holder back with specific information tied to that specific list item stored in the convertView.

Comment: This answer does solve the issue where your data ONLY changes if convertView is null, which just isn't the case after the first time, you are using inner classes. These hold implicit references to the activity they are tied to and will leak the entire activity. You either need to make them static or move them out of the class and give them a WeakReference to the activity.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll look into the video and come back to you if it's not working after the video. Struggling with this problem for a long time.